# How to execute JavaScript in HtmlUnit without running page scripts

Tags: java, javascript, html, facebook, htmlunit

So, I'm having a bit of an issue in HtmlUnit

I'm trying to run a bit of Javascript on Facebook's message page to send someone a message. The JavaScript I'm using is this, and it runs just fine in the browser's console:

```
document.getElementsByName("message_body")[0].value = "test"; var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent'); e.initKeyEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0); document.getElementsByName("message_body")[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

It first selects the message body textarea by its name, types in "test", and then presses the enter key, sending the message.

When trying to use the executeJavaScript() in HtmlUnit method it fails, but not even because of my code.

I'm receiving this error:

```
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java class "com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException" has no public instance field or method named "message". (https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yj/r/zt0nwbhPchP.js#36)
```

...which appears to be an error in Facebook's JavaScript, not mine.

The problem? I can't run any of my own JavaScript on the page without HtmlUnit seeing Facebook's code and breaking with an exception.

Is there any way I could circumvent this? Also, if the script works perfectly fine in the browser, why would it break HtmlUnit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the question is two years old, but in my case if I set 
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false)
I can work around it.